# In Python How Do I re-organise inconsistent columns from Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I have got a bunch of reports, all containing the same information, but the columns are inconsistent in order and titles, so when I run the functions to parse the information I am not getting out what I want.

How can I use python to organise the columns in a consistent way to work with later down the line?

Currently the columns look like;

```
['Comment', 'Rec Date', 'Receipt Number', 'Rec Amt', 'Receipt Method', 'Status']
['Comment', 'State', 'Rec No', 'Rec Date', 'Rec Amt', 'Status']
['Receipt Number', 'Rec Date', 'Rec Amt', 'Comment', 'State', 'Status']
['Comment', 'Receipt Number', 'Rec Date', 'Rec Amt', 'State', 'Rec Method']
['Comment', 'Receipt Number', 'Rec Date', 'Rec Amt', 'Receipt Method', 'State']
['Comment', 'Receipt Number', 'Rec Date', 'Rec Amt', 'State', 'Rec Method']
```

I would like all of these categories to be included as columns. (Points that don't have a value for a specific column would get some placeholder or empty value.)

Comment: is your excel data in python represented as a list of lists?

Comment: Yes, I read in the data using xlrd, remove any blank rows and each row is represented as a list within one big list.

I have then been iterating through the lists to parse the data within them, meaning that when the columns are different it breaks the indexing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) for `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
```

I believe you need `rename` columns by dict and then sort them by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
d = {'Rec No':'Receipt Number', 'Rec Method':'Receipt Method',...}
df = df.rename(columns=d).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Comment: Bloody hell pandas is amazing! Thanks for this, was a great help

Comment: I absolutely agree, pandas is fantastic. Nice day!